# Undefined is not a function when initializing slider on Ghost Blog

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ghost-blog

So I've been struggling with this situation for a while now:

I'm trying to initialize a slider on a Ghost blog theme, but all i get on the console is:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

*Note: The error points to the `.slick([...]);` function.*

- As far as i found out, it could be an Outdated jQuery, or conflict with the `{{ghost_foot}}` helper:

  - Ghost blog uses 1.10.X jQuery version - Slick Slider requires 1.7+, but anyway, I've tried to add the 2.1.3 version after the `{{ghost_foot}}` helper - **sadly, still receiving the same error**
  - I've heard that there's no way of disabling the Ghost jquery default inlcude, so I've tried to remove the `{{ghost_foot}}` helper and including the 2.1.3 jQuery version - **still receiving the same error**
  - Keeping the 1.10.X version, and adding the jQuery Migrate Plugin - **no changes**
  - Pasting the raw jQuery, then the Slick.js on the console, then trying to initilize the slider - **still the same**

#### Now a glimpse of my gruntfile:

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    mangle: false
  },
  combinejs: {
    files: {
      '<%= ghost_location %>content/themes/<%= ghost_theme_name %>/assets/js/all.min.js': 
      [
      'bower_components/treasure/dist/js/treasure.js',
      'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
      'js/parallax.min.js',
      'js/keypress.min.js',
      'bower_components/slick/dist/slick.min.js',
      'js/script.js'
      ]
    }
  }
```

#### The slider loop:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 no-padding slider">
  {{#foreach posts}}
    {{#if featured}}
      <article class="article_pombo col-xs-12 {{post_class}} no-padding featured slide" role="article" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
        <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding a">
          <div class="dummy"></div>
          <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <div class="img-w">
              {{#if image}}
                <img src="{{image}}" alt="{{title}}" title="{{title}}" />
              {{/if}}
            </div>
            <div class="tit-w">
              <h1 class="posttitle_pombo" itemprop="headline"><a href="{{{url}}}" rel="bookmark">{{title}}</a></h1>
              <p itemprop="articleBody">{{excerpt characters="150"}}</p>
              <div class="author_pombo" itemprop="authorName">
                {{#author}}
                  <a href="{{url}}">
                    {{#if image}}
                      <img src="{{image}}" alt="{{name}}" title="{{name}}" />
                    {{else}}
                      {{content characters="0"}}
                    {{/if}}
                  </a>
                  <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
                  <time class="date_pombo" datetime="{{date format="YYYY-MM-DD"}}" itemprop="datePublished">{{date format='dddd DD MMM YYYY'}}</time>
                {{/author}}
              </div>
              {{#if tags}}
                <div class="posttags_pombo">
                  Tags: {{tags separator=" | "}}
                </div>
              {{/if}}
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </article>
    {{/if}}
  {{/foreach}}
</div>
```

#### And the JS:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  wbst.init();
});

var wbst = {
  init: function() {
    this.validate();
    this.allPage();
  },
    allPage: function() {
    tools.vendors.slick();
  }
};

var tools = {
  vendors: {
    slick: function() {
      if (jQuery('.slide').length > 1) {
        jQuery('.slider').slick();
      }
    }
  }
};

// I've stripped it down, to allow better understanding of what may be causing it...
```

Comment: Is slick plugin file being loaded? Is jQuery loading more than once in page?

Comment: It is being loaded - I even tried to add it manually via Console input.
No, jQuery is being loaded just once - Ghost include it automatically via `{{ghost_foot}}`

Comment: is plugin loading after jQuery?

Comment: Yes it is being loaded after the jQuery.

Comment: Can't help without a live link

Comment: Sorry, i don't have it online. I'll try to put it online, then.

Comment: Your calling `wbst.init()` before you have defined it, hence `undefined`. Try calling it after you have defined it :D

Comment: @mikedidthis that's not the problem at all. Because everything works. `wbst.init()` works, and it get to the `tools.vendors.slick()` function (I've tried inserting a `console.log` and the log show up in the console) - Just saying: I've tried to put it after defining it, and no changes. And, even calling `tools.vendors.slick()` directly in the console give me nothing